# rendering empty partial if its not available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, partial

I am refactoring my code. I had a lot of if-else statements at various places mostly for rendering partials. 
So, I used the code below. Though the code works, for some account types where partial is not available, I get an error.

**'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object that returns a valid partial path.**

```
- account_type = 'Analyst' # it could be analyst/role/admin
:partial => "control-panel/add-#{account_type}"
```

Is there a way to render empty partial if the partial is not available in the specified directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have created partials for `'Analyst'` and `'Admin'` then you can simply put them in a hash like so:

```
- account_type_partials = { 'Analyst' => 'analyst', 'Admin' => 'admin' }
- account_type = account_type_partials['Analyst']
= render :partial => "control-panel/add-#{account_type}" if account_type
```

However, I'd encourage you to move these two variables to your controller's method where they can be reused:

```
def account_type_partials
  { 'Analyst' => 'analyst', 'Admin' => 'admin' }
end
```

Now, in different methods of your controller:

```
@account_type = account_type_partials['Analyst'] # or 'Admin' / 'Role'
```

then in view:

```
= render :partial => "control-panel/add-#{@account_type}" if @account_type
```